# Persistent error on Samsung Galaxy Note 5

Tags: android, adb

## Persistent error on Samsung Galaxy Note 5

this is a weird issue that i am having for almost a year now, i'll try to be brief.

### background story (What i think happened)

I own a Chinese aftermarket car infotainment system, running android 4.4. So, being the obsolete piece of **** that it is, i started digging around, and found out that it has something called **Device link** or something along those lines.

you have to download an app called EasyConnection from the play store, enable developer mode, and enable usb debugging, i know that's not the safest thing to do with Chinese stuff, but that's the only option i have at my disposal, so i have to manage.

anyway, it worked flawlessly for a year or so, then suddenly it refused to connect, with an endless **connecting** message. and my phone started giving me the **Attention** message, this was a year ago, and never worked since.

```
Attention

The connected device is unable to access data on this device. Reconnect the USB cable and try again.

Android File Transfer or Samsung Smart Switch must be installed on Mac OS X devices. To download Android File Transfer, go to https://www.android.com/filetransfer, or to download Samsung Smart Switch, go to https://www.samsung.com/smartswitch.
```

### Phone behavior

Since then, whenever i connect my phone to my PC, either running windows or linux, it displays the **Attention** message. i can access files on my phone no problem, and it is not driver related, as this happens regardless of what driver is installed, or in the case of linux, no driver is required.

### Android development

Now, a couple of months back, i decided to dabble in android development , as i have a couple of sysadmin years under my belt, and a beginner level knowledge of a couple of programming languages, so i thought android development would be fun, but here is the problem.

While my device is hooked up to android studio, i get this aforementioned error on random long intervals, but i am able to run my apps from android studio to my phone no problem. So i started to link everything together, and thought to seek help here on reddit after some fruitless internet diving.

---

### note

I did a factory reset for my phone a month or so ago, so the only step remaining in my mind right now is to re-flash the stock firmware (i'm on stock for security reasons), but i am reluctant to do so because of the hassle of re-configuring my device again.

I'm hoping to accomplish the following :

- Resolve the cause of the error.
- See if my car system works with my phone after the error is resolved

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As the error states you need to install one of these applications to be able to see the phone's file system. You don't need to do it if you just want to debug

Comment: As i said, this error occurs regardless of what system i use, in linux, you don't need drivers, and on my car infotainment system, this error does appears too. This error didn't appear for the first year of use with the car system, and doesn't ever appear on my other android phone running android 6.0